# There are differences between my Asset (DONUT) and the final rendered Asset

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine

My final render does not resemble my actual model. If you look at the right side of the icing in the picture before render you will see no holes. The final render to so much. Any ideas?

Pre render
[image]

Pre Render with shaded Cycles
[image]

After render.
[image]

https://blend-exchange.com/b/zg8XgSvk/

Comment: Check my edits, the answer solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't attached your .blend file, so it is impossible to know the correct problem.

However, I guess that you must have a modifier applied to one of your objects which is hidden in the render or viewport. If you have a subdivision surface, then probably the render count will be different from your viewport level.

[image]

**EDIT:**

After checking your file, I see that on the torus object (the bread) the render and viewport levels of the Subdivision Surface are different. Make them the same to fix the intersection. By the way, instead of using two subdiv modifiers, simply use one and increase the count.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I am still very new and i do appreciate the help aswell as the tip. have a great day!

Comment: @Antondastupid No problem, have fun!